# Carrierwave Profile_Picture Uploader with Devise not uploading in Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, carrierwave

I have a user model created with devise. I want to allow these users to upload a profile picture.

I am using carrierwave for this and followed the rails cast to do so. However the uploader will not work.

I had a look at https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-use-carrierwave-with-devise

But this did not really help. I am now getting this error:

```
NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#update
undefined method `marked_for_destruction?' for #<ProfilePictureUploader:0x007fa585b7a638>
```

I cannot see anythign that is wrong with my code, I followed the rails cast perfectly. The only thing I can think of is that the railscast uses rails 3 and i am using rails 4

Any ideas?

Comment: you override `Devise::RegistrationsController` ?

Comment: you do not understand, I ask whether you copied this controller? in your project?

Comment: Sorry, no I have not. I just followed the rails cast on this

Comment: error may be hiding anywhere, very little information to track.

Comment: I'll take a look and see whats happening. Its not too important at the minute. Since you are very responsive! Could I ask you a quick question. I am using acts_as_taggable_on for 2 tagging models, topics and places. I have a problem that a place can be 2 words e.g New York. So in the URL it is /places/New%20York. I tried the friendly_id gem but its not working with acts_as_taggable_on. Any ideas?

Comment: can you show me some code or github?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might mount uploader on the wrong field.

Checkout `mount_uploader :file, AttachmentUploader` is on the right field.